# How do you JSON Marshall a pq.NullTime in UTC rather than the local timezone?

Tags: postgresql, go

I have dates in postgres table. The dates are stored with a UTC timezone.

Example from python.

```
roster = Roster.objects.get(id=266438)
roster.start_timestamp
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 15, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

When I marshall these dates from within go lib/pq my local time zone is somehow being applied.

```
func (nt *pq.NullTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !nt.Valid {
        return []byte("\"\""), nil
    }
    val := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", nt.Time.Format("01/02/2006 15:04:05"))
    fmt.Println("Marshalling FMPDateTime", nt, val)
    return []byte(val), nil
}
```

Example log:

```
Marshalling DateTime &{2018-09-08 00:30:00 +0930 ACST true} "09/08/2018 00:30:00"
```

2018-09-08 00:30:00 +0930 ACST *is* 2018-09-07 15:00:00 UTC.

How do you JSON Marshall a pq.NullTime in UTC rather than the local timezone?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries usually construct `time.Time` values using the local timezone, but the time instant is still the same, so you shouldn't worry about that.

If you want to display / output the time in UTC zone specifically, then "switch" your time to UTC timezone. For this, you may use the [`Time.UTC()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC) method:

```
val := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", nt.Time.UTC().Format("01/02/2006 15:04:05"))
```

That's all.

Also note that if your `NullTime` is not valid, I would rather output JSON `null` instead of an empty string.

Comment: I prefer null as well. We're making a cache for a FileMaker database.  The FileMaker Data API uses "" for null.